# How to run 2 npm commands in Windows command line (bash, babun) from package.json?

Tags: node.js, bash, command-line-interface, oh-my-zsh

I just cloned project repository that I build with Mac. The project is run via package.json defined scripts, such as:

```
    }
    "scripts": {
        "start": "npm run sync & npm run watch-sg",
        ...,
        ...
    }
```

When i run this command only first task runs on windows. Why cannot i run mutliple task connected with "&" ?

I tried with bash, zsh (babun).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a second `&`.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run sync && npm run watch-sg",
    ...,
    ...
}
```

Comment: tried, does not work. Just to clarify commands one by one work just fine.